# lost bitcoin on electrum - wallet closed after transaction went through?

Tags: wallet, electrum, lost-bitcoins

i'm noob to bitcoin and lack advanced knowledge of how these wallets work.
 i followed guides on how to buy bitcoin and seemingly the transaction went fine, until my electrum wallet suddenly closed and when i opened it back up i could not find my transaction in history, my recieving address changed and the address i used to buy  bitcoin can not be found anywhere. 
here is a link to the transaction https://blockchain.info/da/address/157gZExbGA27R33AFHmQS41EzFxXoUpBjP

and an image of the receipt after purchase
[image]
did i screw this up completely or can i still get my bitcoin into my electrum wallet?

Comment: Things to check: 1. is your Electrum connected, and have a green dot on the lower right corner? 2. Go to addresses tab, can you find your receiving address there?

Comment: yes me wallet is connected, and no i cannot find the receiving address under the adress tab

Comment: I don't know why the receiving address disappeared, but you can try to restore the wallet by using the same seed you created the wallet with. Electrum is a HD wallet, so you will get the same sequence of private keys, public keys, public addresses using the same seed every time. As long as your Electrum client is authentic, this is probably just a bug and you funds are safe.

Comment: i restored the wallet using the seed, but still not finding the address i used for my purchase.

Comment: Hmm.. weird. Here is what you can do: Open Electrum, click on on wallet, then master public keys. Copy the master public key and paste it in blockchain.info/xpub/"your master public key here" without the quotes. It will show you all the transactions related to your current Electrum seed. Is the 'lost' transaction listed there?

Comment: no, it says no transactions are found on this address

Comment: Well, if you are absolutely sure that you saw the transaction in Electrum, and the address has now disappeared even using the same seed. There is only one thing left to do: Submit an issue directly to the Electrum developers. https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues and mention that you tried with your master public key and didn't find the corresponding transaction.

Answer (score -1):

> Hmm.. weird. Here is what you can do: Open Electrum, click on on
>   wallet, then master public keys. Copy the master public key and paste
>   it in blockchain.info/xpub/"your master public key here" without the
>   quotes. It will show you all the transactions related to your current
>   Electrum seed. Is the 'lost' transaction listed there?

Well, if you are absolutely sure that you saw the transaction in Electrum, and the address has now disappeared even using the same seed. There is only one thing left to do: Submit an issue directly to the Electrum developers. github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues and mention that you tried with your master public key and didn't find the corresponding transaction.